# C# Piping commands into PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

I need to run two powershell commands one after the other, should I create a pipeline twice or is there a better option? Thanks

```
Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rc);
            myRunSpace.Open();

            Pipeline pipeLine = myRunSpace.CreatePipeline();

            using (pipeLine)
            {
                Command myCommand = new Command("Get-Command...");
            }

            Pipeline pipeLine2 = myRunSpace.CreatePipeline();

            using (pipeLine2)
            {
                Command myCommand = new Command("Get-Command...");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

A pipeline is, according to msdn, like an "assembly line", so if the results of the first command have nothing to do with the second command, you do not need a Pipeline, you can use a ScriptBlock instead, and invoke it with a RunspaceInvoke object.

See an example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2006/04/25/583250.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Would you be happier with your code if you wrote:

```
using (Pipeline pipeLine = myRunSpace.CreatePipeline())
{
    Command myCommand = new Command("Get-Command...");
}
```

?

Comment: Would this make any difference? Thanks